# A sequence of HTTP requests are not coming in order.Then an old request may be displayed instead on the last one

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, httprequest

I created the interface of my web application using Angular 8. The problem is that when I send multiple requests they's not arriving in order. This couses a lot of issues. For example when the user navigates pages rapidly, sometimes the wrong page is displayed.

- What's the best solution using RxJS?
- Can I do this using an Interceptor for all of my request?

This is an example snippet that retrieves items using HttpClient:

```js
listOptions = {
  start: 0,
  length: 10
};

private fillCards() {
  this.companyService.getList(this.listOptions).subscribe(res => {
    if (res.code === 1) {
      this.list = res.data; // This list is displayed in the view
    }
  });
}

public pageChange() {
  // Set list parameters
  this.listOptions.start = (this.page - 1) * this.pageSize;
  this.listOptions.length = this.pageSize;

  // Reload the cards
  this.fillCards();
}
```

list function in company service:

```js
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private appSettings: AppSettings) {}

getList(options = new ApiListOptions()) {
  return this.http.post<ApiResponse<CompanyGet[]>>(
    this.appSettings.ApiRoot + 'company/list',
    options
  );
}
```

Comment: first of all you will run into memory leaks as you are creating and subscribing to observables on your page changes. second in this code if you want to hack it update the getList function to return back with options in the response, then in your fillCards function response inside subscribe compare to current page and response page numbers if they dont match discard the response. The correct way of doing this would be to abort the http call when you identify page change there should be a single observable which will start from your pagechange, there is also another way maybe add a debounce

Comment: Thanks. How can I prevent memory leak? How should I use debounce? Can I use it inside my interceptor?

Comment: you can add loader once user click on the page and hide loader once request comes back.To prevent memory leak its always a good practice to unsubscribe from all subscriptions on component destroy

Comment: If you are using rxjs, then u can try to use the switchMap(). It will cancel the previous request, executes the current request, so you will get the latest value from server always.

Comment: @Sudhakar Thanks, I tried to use switchMap but don't know how to use it. I'm a beginner at RxJS

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, everytime the user navigates to the next page, you fire a request to the backend to load that page. If they click multiple times on the next page button, this leads to multiple requests being fired in parallel, and the last one to return "wins", i.e. those results will be displayed.

There are a number of ways around this. One - you could disable the navigation button in the UI until the latest request completes. This way the user would have to wait until being able to navigate again.

Also in the UI you could offer the user the possibility to jump to a specific result page, so that they don't have to click 5 times to get to page 5.

Another way would be not to fire the http request immediately upon a click, but to wait for a time instead to see if the user still clicks the button to get to a page further away. You would use `debounceTime` to delay the http request.

See the following example on how to achieve this: https://angular-s3qpgc.stackblitz.io

Your component would maintain a "click queue", and place any button clicks into it:

```
clickQueue = new Subject();
pageNumber = 0;

getDataAsync(): void {
  this.clickQueue.next(this.number++);
}
```

You would subscribe to this queue with a `debounceTime(500)`, so that you only act once the user has stopped clicking for 500ms.
The `switchMap` operator ensures that, should the user begin clicking again after a request has been sent, the pending http call is canceled (and its results get discarded)

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.clickQueue.pipe(
    debounceTime(500),
    switchMap(num => this.callService(num))
  ).subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result);
  });
}
```

In my example, the `callService` function simulates the http call, which would return after a random time between 500-1000ms.

```
callService(number) {
  return new Observable(subscriber => {
    setTimeout(() => {
    subscriber.next(number);
    subscriber.complete();
    }, 500 + Math.random() * 500);
  });
```

}

In the example, you can see what happens when you click the 'Get data now' button - which is what happens in your current case. As opposed to the 'Get data async', which uses debounceTime and switchMap, which would result in the intended behaviour.

**Final note**: As others have said, **everytime** you call `subscribe()` on an Observable, you must call `unsubscribe` at a later point as well, otherwise you are creating memory leaks and strange bugs in your application. That's another topic, you can check for example this article: https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-best-way-to-unsubscribe-rxjs-observable-in-the-angular-applications-d8f9aa42f6a0

Answer (score 0):

Add a Subject called finalise to your component

```
finalise = new Subject<void>();
```

and pipe a take until finalise before your subscription.

```
this.companyService.getList(this.listOptions).pipe(takeUntil(finalise))
```

And add a ngOnDestroy

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.finalise.next();
}
```

This will clean up your subscription and cancel any outstanding http requests. You should do this with all subscriptions so you don't have any orphan subscriptions and memory leaks.

You could also take a look at a library I wrote to manage so of the http requests called ngx-rxcache. https://medium.com/@adrianbrand/angular-state-management-with-rxcache-468a865fc3fb

Comment: OP problem is ` when the user navigates pages rapidly, sometimes the wrong page is displayed` and your solution is for memory leaks

Comment: No, this is so that http request fired get cancelled. OP is saying that http request don't come in order so this cancels ones they wont need.

Comment: @AdrianBrand Thanks, but This will not solve my problem. Because my problem occurs through the life cycle of the component. For example, pagination requests are requested multiple times before destroying the component.

Comment: try use async pipe in html, it auto unsubscribe for you